# Powershell to group items separated by commas as they relate to another value on other column

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

need some help with powershell and manipulating csv files, as I'm a newbie trying to learn.

I've got a .csv file with several columns, for now lets refer to them as A, B, C, D
In column 'A' I have URLs, Column 'B' I have Groups, C and D are of o importance for this example.

so as far as the values in the cells below each column,  obviously the Values of URL are tied to the Value of those under Group Column 'B'.

Sample csv:

```
URL,Groups,x,y
test1.org,TestGroup,xxx,yyy
test2.org,TestGroup,xxx,yyy
Test3.com,TestGroup,xxx,yyy
Check.com,CheckGroup,xxx,yyy
Random.1.com,RandomGroup,xxx,yyy
random.22.org,RandomGroup,xxx,yyy
```

So what I'm trying to do is group these in a way that it looks like this:

```
Groups,URL,x,y
TestGroup,"test1.org,test2.org,test3.org",xxx,yyy
CheckGroup,Check.com,xxx,yyy
RandomGroup,"Random.1.com,random.22.org",xxx,yyy
```

I tried the following:

```
$Dir = "FileLocation\Data"
$Data1 = import-csv $Dir\my.csv

$Data = $Data1 | Select Groups, URL | Group-Object Groups 

$Data | export-cdv $Dir\result.csv
```

This results in a table that does not work for me as it turns the grouping into an array.

I want to be able to sort unique by group on the original csv and import the values of the Group's URL as they relate in the same cell separated by commas.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a good case for a hashtable magic, create a hashtable and append to it, using Group Column as a key.

```
$data = import-csv 'path'
$hashtable = @{}
foreach ($item in $data) { $hashtable[$($item.Groups)] += "$($item.URL), " }
```

the only downside is that there is an extra comma at the end of each key.

Comment: `$a` should be `$data `and `$b` = `$hashtable` or vice versa?

Comment: So Im assuming what you provided is the script of its own and not an append to what I had....with that, When I run it I get an error message for every group saying " Cannot convert value "TestGroup" to type "System.Int32".  Error: "Input string was not in correct format."  It then displays the foreach line highlighting the ($item.URL).  It repeats this error for every group name line.

Comment: I have no idea what you did, I've copy pasted your csv to a file and did this and it worked.

Comment: My bad, this does work!! thanks.  the csv I'm actually using must have something different.  Let me check whats going on.

Comment: Ok, so I mistakenly had an (s) in Groups in this sample vs the original csv header.  So now that I have this new hash table, how do I re insert it into the original csv  so that the rest of the column that were related to each group also show up.  I guess at this point the original needs to be sorted -Unique.

Comment: well, that's another question, accept this as an answer to this question and start new one @acastrellon23