# Add newly generated hash table to existing csv where value of a column match

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

The following is a continual of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42539117/1630171) that got answered.

Original CSV has the following values:

```
URL,Groups,contact,number
test1.org,TestGroup,Ax;Bx;Cx,555
test2.org,TestGroup,Ax;Bx;Cx,555
Test3.com,TestGroup,Ax;Bx;Cx,555
Check.com,CheckGroup,Rx;Tx,333
Random.1.com,RandomGroup,Gy;Fy;Hy,999
random.22.org,RandomGroup,Gy;Fy;Hy,999
```

Someone generously helped out providing code to generate a hashtable that grouped this by `Groups` and set the all URLs for each group into one separated by comma (`,`).

Code was:

```bsh
$data = Import-Csv 'path'
$hashtable = @{}
foreach ($item in $data) {
    $hashtable[$($item.Groups)] += "$($item.URL); "
}
```

I need 2 things answered:

1. How do I remove the semicolon (`;`) of the last value in the group?
2. How do I get this new hashtable back to my original CSV?

The logic Im thinking is `Sort -Unique` the original and for each group name that matches that of the hashtable insert the value of the hash table in the URL field.  Something like that.

Expected end result should be something like (ordered):

```
Groups,URL,contact,number
TestGroup,test1.org;test2.org;Test3.com,Ax;Bx;Cx,555
CheckGroup,Check.com,Rx;Tx,333
RandomGroup,Random.1.com;random.22.org,Gy;Fy;Hy,999
```

Comment: Will the same `Groups` value always be followed by the same `contact` and `number` values?

Comment: What happens in the original csv, the report that spits this csv out generated the URLs on separate lines for the group.  So thats why you see a group that had Contact and number tied together, now got duplicated because the URL was spit up in separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group `$data` by the `Groups` field, then expand the `URL` field for each group and join the resulting array with semicolons:

```
$data | Group-Object Groups | ForEach-Object {
    $hashtable[$_.Name] = @($_.Group | Select-Object -Expand URL) -join ';'
}
```

Then remove the URL field from the original data, select the unique records, and add the grouped URLs back in:

```
$data | Select-Object -Property * -Exclude URL |
    Select-Object -Unique * |
    Select-Object *,@{n='URL';e={$hashtable[$_.Groups]}}
```

Comment: Retracted my comment this only needed a variable assigned to call the new table.

Comment: Question, is this assuming that the data in original is sorted to match that of the hash table?? or can we add something to ensure that the name in the hash table matches the name of the group on the original before adding the grouped URLs??

Comment: What do you think the hashtable lookup `$hashtable[$_.Groups]` does?